# Is it possible to write c malloc function code like this

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc, structure

confusing on allocating memory on the heap?

If i write to initialize the variable in heap memory like that

```
((struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)).data=2
```

Can I write like this instead of using the pointer.
If I declare node type variable than it is possible to write like this or do not?
If I do not use pointer by access direct address.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Please pick one of C and C++. They are different languages.

Comment: Is this question about C or C++? I'm asking because the answer for C++ (this is not OK) will be different from the answer for C (this is probably OK)…

Comment: You can write `malloc(...)->data = 2` but nobody would do that since it's completely pointless code.

Comment: can i access linked list node and assign a value to it like this

Comment: @hacksark No, because a linked list, like any other C code, has to keep track of all items that are dynamically allocated. Allocating something and tossing it out in the wild achieves nothing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information instead of writing comments.

Comment: use `calloc()` to initialize (to `0`, `0.0`, `NULL`, ...) the memory obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible of course:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct a
{
    int a; 
    float b;
};

void *foo()
{
    void *v;
    ((struct a *)malloc(sizeof(struct a))) -> b = 4.0f;
    (*((struct a *)malloc(sizeof(struct a)))).b = 6.0f;

    *((struct a *)malloc(sizeof(struct a)))  = (struct a){5, 8.0f};

    ((struct a *)(v = malloc(sizeof(struct a)))) -> b = 4.0f;

    return v;

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/suW4sp

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question depends on your definition of "possible".

It is definetely possible to write and compile such code and it would be a correct c program, but it won't make any sence since you've never stored an actual address of data you've just written, so you have no means to acess it later in program. Each time you're calling `malloc` function, it returns new address of newly allocated area of memory, so every time you're trying to access your data like that, it would be different data with different address.

So, if you want to allocate a `struct node` dynamically and use it further inside your program, you have to write it like this:

```c
struct node* tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
tmp->data = 2;
```

Then you may use that `tmp` pointer for whatever suits your needs.

Also, don't forget to de-allocate it using `free` when you no longer need this data.

Comment: Then tell me how to write in c

Comment: You literally have an answer inside your own question. To work with dynamically-allocated memory you have to use pointers.

Comment: No, the answer is not in the question, because `.` is not the correct operator for that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil well yes, but OP asks about whether it's possible to use `malloc` like that without pointers. However, I've added a correct example with `->` operator to my answer.

Comment: @hacksark see it in my ansswer